# xcode debugger value of expression

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In XCode, I insert a breakpoint at some line..

Say that line is:

```
abc = [books valueForKey:@"OfficialName"];
x = [appDelegate.books count];
```

My question is in the debugger, if I hover over say abc, it will display the value

But if I want to see the runtime value of an expression say `"appDelegate.books count"`

it does not show the value. How can I get the value of this expression like a normal var ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat unorthodox, but in order to find what you get in that for loop (see hmthur's comment in my other answer):

> for (x=0;x<[arr count];x++)

Firstly, spread the loop over three seperate lines, so that you can debug step them one bit at a time:

```
for (x = 0;
     x < [arr count];
     x++)
```

Now put a breakpoint at the start of the for loop.

Step down so that x < [arr count] has been executed, but not the x++

Now in the watch window of the debugger, open up the registers group.

The result returned by [arr count] will be present in the $eax register.

This is most unorthodox, don't rely on it for developing life-critical software!
Stick with my original answer in the interests of sanity.

Answer (score 5):

You can determine variable value using debugger console:

```
print (int) [arr count]
```

or use command `po` to print object's description

```
po objectName
```

Comment: Note that `po` is an abbreviation for `print-object`; similarly, `print` can be abbreviated `p`.

Comment: Note also that the thing to the right of the `p` or `po` command can be any legal Objective-C expression, though message expressions may need a cast operator (so gdb knows how to format the resulting value) as Dmitry shows above.

Comment: Yep, and note also that gdb can't recognize object's property getters: if you need to print `object`'s `property` you need to call `po [object property]` for object-type properties and `p (type)[object property]` for non-object properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a variable, it's a message. But the answer will be stored in x, so hover over that instead.

Comment: I know in this case I assign it to x..so it can be found...But my questions is general
e.g. in case we have for (x=0;x<[arr count];x++)

and i need to find "arr count"

How can I do that?

Comment: The "count" method will have it's own variables and code in there. Unfortunately, because it is part of the runtime, you won't be able to step into it with the debugger to see those variables. Imagine you wrote your own "count" method, you could step into that, and examine those variables within. The solution to your problem would really be to assign [arr count] to a variable before the for loop. It would also be more efficient to do that, rather than sending the count message every pass of the for loop.